# How to compare current time with old time in PHP

Tags: php

I have stored date field at DB.

In PHP, i am getting that field and converted into date.

I want to compare that time with current time. If that difference is above 60 minutes. It will return some value.

I dont know how to write logic for that

```
$lastUpdatedField = $rows_fetch['lastUpdatedTime'];
$lastUpdatedDate = new DateTime($lastUpdatedField);

$nowDate = new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'));
```

I have old date&time is in $lastUpdatedDate variable, and current time is in $nowDate.

How to compare these two

Comment: have you looked into http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php ?

Comment: +1 for using DateTime class.

Comment: Side note: `new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'))` is completely redundant (and probably has issues with time zones). Just omit the constructor argument entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$interval = $nowDate->diff($lastUpdatedDate);
echo $interval->h;
```

DateDiff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

DateInterval: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 0):

First convert the current time and old time to one unit like Unix timestamp passing it through strtotime(). Then differentiate both the timestamp to get the difference between two times.

```
$difftime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($rows_fetch['lastUpdatedTime']);
```

Then convert the difference to days as follows :

```
$days=$difftime/24*60*60;
```

Once you get the days you can get the minutes from it as below to compare to meet your need.

```
$timediff = $days * 24 * 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had The same problem earlier its actually quit simple

heres the piece where you declare your variables

```
$lastUpdateddate = new DateTime($lastUpdatedField);
$nowDate = new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'));
```

Then you have  to convert them to second - format so that you can do math with them 
To do that use strtotime

```
$Diff = strtotime($lastUpdatedDate) - strtotime($nowDate);
```

Then just check to see if the difference in time is more then 60 minutes,
So devide by 60 seconds to get minutes and by 60 to get hours

```
if ($diff/60/60 <= 1){
    //do your thing here
{
```